# writeLines behavior with special characters

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, rstudio, special-characters

When running this following line in R (R Studio):

```
writeLines("hello \U1F30D",useBytes = T)
```

I get different results.

With a PC, I get

```
hello ðŸŒ
```

or

```
writeLines("hello \U1F30D",useBytes = F)
hello <U+0001F30D>
```

And with a mac

```
writeLines("hello \U1F30D",useBytes = F)
hello
```

I think that the behavior is not due to the machine. It should be the encoding. But I checked the encoding of R Studio, it is UTF-8 for both. So now I have no idea why there are different behavior, could anyone explain the differences?

Comment: I suspect that this is related to the fact that Windows does not support UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a somewhat long-form answer to this question here: https://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2018/02/21/string-encoding-and-r/

The short answer: `writeLines("<text>", useBytes = FALSE)` will attempt to *re-encode* the provided text to the native encoding. This works on Unix systems using a UTF-8 locale (which is the default nowadays) but will fail when this is not the case (ie, on Windows). In effect, you need something like:

```
writeLines("<text>", file, useBytes = TRUE)
readLines(file, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Note that diagnosing encoding issues on Windows can be challenging as R will fairly aggressively re-encode UTF-8 text into the native encoding (sometimes attempting to round-trip UTF-8 -> native -> UTF-8) and that conversion is usually lossy.